# VSCode build recipes needing to build multiple times before working

Tags: vscode

I'm not really sure how to word this, apologies as I am semi-new to LaTeX on VSCode. I have a rather large project with a .bib, a .bst and a .cls (I am using a research journal's specific style file and template). At some point in development, VSCode has started to struggle to build the LaTeX project, in that all the citations, equation references, section references etc. become "undefined" even though they are all clearly defined. Uploading the project into something like Overleaf, everything compiles without any error.

I have discovered a workaround of using the specific combination of recipes: Run latexmk, then pdflatex->bibtex->pdflatex*2, then latexmk again, and the document compiles normally. If I compile using any other recipe or not in that exact order, I get either a compiler error or it compiles with the aforementioned broken references.

I wondered if there is any way to figure out what exactly is going wrong in the VSCode recipes that isn't going wrong in Overleaf.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: The output of LaTeX compiler can be obtained from the "Output" tab in the bottom panel. You can compare the output of `latexmk` called by VS Code to that from Overleaf.

Comment: @AlanXiang I'm not really sure how to interpret what I'm looking at. Latexmk seems to compile all the main .tex file but for some reason cannot find my bibliography nor resolve the section and equation references defined in the main .tex file